# Why is System process listening on Port 80?

Tags: windows-7, windows

I am running Windows 7 RC1.  I have multiple issues getting IIS to work on my system and today when I installed a new application and I tried to load it using http:\localhost\MyApplication I get absolutely no errors and I get no page load.  Just a pretty, white blank page.

I did some digging and I found something about some other process listening on port 80 so I did a scan using `netstat -aon | findstr 0.0:80` and discovered that PID 4 was listening on that port.

PID 4 does not show in task manager so I fired up Process Explorer and it showed me that PID 4 is the System process.  (Multiple google searches seems to indicate that System always uses PID 4).

Since then I am basically stuck.  I have no idea why System needs port 80 and what to do about it.

If you google the following strings you will find two helpful Experts-Exchange articles at the top of the search results and you can read them for some helpful information.

(If I gave the direct URL to the pages then Experts-Exchange would ask you to pay...but when you click on the results from a google search you can scroll all of the way to the bottom to read the exchanges.)

Here are the google searches...
"System Process is listening on port 80 (Vista)"
"SYSTEM Process is listening on Port 80 and Preventing IIS Default Website from Running"

The last entry from the first result showed how to do a trace of http.sys at the following URL:

http://blogs.msdn.com/wndp/archive/2007/01/18/event-tracing-in-http-sys-part-1-capturing-a-trace.aspx

Trace showed nothing useful. Any thoughts?

Comment: Same problems here, except, I tried all answers as suggested and nothing. I can't just start shutting down services because this is an off-site cloud server.

Comment: Did you mean that you are running Windows 7 SP1, and not RC1?

Comment: Are you running Skype? https://support.skype.com/en/faq/FA148/which-ports-need-to-be-open-to-use-skype

Comment: Probably that does not actually solve your problem, anyway you can change the Apache port to `8080`... Well, that is not a solution, but may work temporarily until you get the proper solution... @rakslice solution solved the problem to me

Comment: The skype thing is the solution! shutdown skype and start apache. done!

Comment: Solution for Windows 8: http://www.rejetto.com/forum/hfs-~-http-file-server/port-80-already-used-in-windows-8-solution/

Comment: HTTP service state can help you to identify the running services in case of System process with PID 4. Run `netsh http show servicestate` and look at _Registered URLs_ or _Logging information_ for more info.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

This post on [Getting Apache to run on port 80 on Windows 7](http://web.archive.org/web/20150113180748/http://www.cameroncooke.com/2009/01/25/windows-7-uses-port-80-and-makes-it-impossible-to-install-apache-solution/) (internet archive) describes your point.

It seems the '`http.sys`' (Windows Remote Management?) service is enabled by default in Windows 7.
Run through the comments on that link for some more notes...

<sub>the hypen-site does not necessarily have the only answers.</sub>

Comment: Another great article: http://www.devside.net/wamp-server/opening-up-port-80-for-apache-to-use-on-windows

Comment: And this is still relevant today with Windows 8.1

Comment: The site is offline.  Can you add the essential information to the answer?

Comment: For me it was the World Wide Web Publish Service - was set to automatic by default, and must use port 80.

Comment: Upgraded from windows 7 to windows 10 and it turned on World Wide Web Publish Service to automatic.  Crazy because I don't even use IIS.

Answer (score 49):

'Web Deployment Agent Service' runs on port 80 as System. You might have this running if you are using WebMatrix.

Comment: Related link: http://eat.cheezburger.com/author/johnc/.  I uninstalled the two porgrams listed: "Microsft Web Deploy 2.0" and "Web Deployment Tool" (as well as WebMatrix itself)

Comment: Related link: http://www.remkoweijnen.nl/blog/2012/01/02/system-process-pid-4-is-listening-on-port-80/

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5867392 for info on how to change this port.

Comment: I Stopped the Web Deployment Agent Service and set it to Manual start, then confirmed that I can still Publish to IIS on this server from Visual Studio and it's all good.  Port 80 is now available to me, and my other functionality still works.

Comment: `net stop "Web Deployment Agent Service"` freed up 80 for me.

Answer (score 46):

Open Services.msc and stop this service "Sql server reporting services(MSSQLSERVER)"

[image]

I had tried EVERYTHING, but that worked for me:

further instructions on how to stop that service are below

1. Right click on **My Computer**
2. Select **Manage**
3. Double click **Services and Applications**
4. Then double click **Services**
5. Right click on **"Sql server reporting services(MSSQLSERVER)"**
6. Select **Stop**
   ...and voila, port 80 was released

Comment: +1. It was indeed SQL Server in my case.

Comment: This worked for me too. I stopped all of the SQL related services (including this one) and port 80 was released.

Comment: +1 but I do need SSRS running so I guess going forward I need to tell SSRS to use a different port?

Comment: "Not using that port? I'll take that! Oh sorry did you need that? Didn't you get the memo?"

Comment: this worked for me.. I didn't expect it because SQL server uses 3306 by default.. but indeed.. SQL server reporting uses port 80.

Comment: @AssafLevy your comment is a disservice to people and clouds things and might make some think the answer isn't as good as it is. It's not SQL Server, it's SQL server reporting. SQL server runs on 3306. SQL server reporting is the thing that is the issue and runs on port 80

Answer (score 24):

You can stop the HTTP service temporarily from the command line:

1. Run an administrator command prompt (e.g. Start, search for `cmd`, right click on it, choose "Run as administrator", approve the UAC prompt if any.)
2. Type `net stop HTTP`
3. If there are other running services that depend on the HTTP service, you'll get a list; double check to see if there's anything listed there you can't bear to do without. Or, if you're just stopping HTTP to use port 80 temporarily, make a note of those dependent services that you'll want to restart once you're done with the port.  Either way, if it's okay, enter `y` to continue.
4. Some dependent services might throw up stop control warnings that cancel the operation; just repeat `net stop HTTP` until it is stopped (i.e. until it says `The HTTP service was stopped successfully.`)
5. Later on, you can restart any of the dependent services, using `net start`  or by using the Services item in Administrative Tools (open it more quickly by <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> running `services.msc`) where you can pick the services from a list, and the HTTP service will be started again automatically.

Comment: This is very helpful to determine the dependent services - thanks!

Comment: this was the solution for me!

Comment: For me, it stopped all related services, then said "Cannot stop HTTP service", and starting `net stop http` again tells me to "try again later". What is wrong with my system :-)

Comment: Using `net stop HTTP` worked for me.

Comment: If you're getting a `try again later message`, you may be running the Microsoft Web Deployment Service. http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2597817 If you're actually using that to maintain IIS you probably didn't want to be stopping HTTP in the first place =).

Comment: doing net stop http, from administrative, i get "The HTTP service could not be stopped"  then "The service is starting or stopping.  Please try again later"

Comment: @barlop  re that command not working for me, for me it was stopping the "sql server reporting" service, a solution suggested in another answer to this question, that worked.

Answer (score 3):

telnet localhost 80 returns HttpAPI/2.0 which in turn means to "Sql server reporting service". Stopping the same releases port 80.

Comment: I found that SQL server reporting services was also the culprit.

Comment: This is a useful debug tool, to use 'telnet' to get more information than a web browser will give you. Thanks. SQL server reporting services was the culprit in my case too.

Answer (score 0):

Take ProcessExplorer, run it, open TCP/IP properties of every process (service), find process (service) that listening to http (80) port and switch it off.

I found Autodesk EDM Server was listening to http (80) port.

Comment: This doesn't work for services running inside system (ie, with a PID of 4)

Comment: I think you are better off doing 'netstat -anbo'. It will tell you straight up what is on port 80 ... except if it is PID 4.