# Where is the default web root folder in Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, webserver

I want to put a simple HTML page for anyone accessing my IP address via browser. I haven't installed any third-party web server (like XAMPP) and IIS is not installed either, but pointing my web browser to http://localhost/ gives no error, but a blank page.

Still, I cannot find where the webroot folder is. Putting `index.html` in `Users\Public\Public Documents` does not work.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why is System listening on port 8000?](https://superuser.com/questions/360236/why-is-system-listening-on-port-8000)

Answer (score 1):

When the browser opens localhost page, right click on it and choose "View Page Source". Find several file names, like favicon.ico, other images and folders that are referenced there. Then search for these files and folders on your computer.

For ASP.Net, the root folder was the folder of the ASP.Net sample application that I've wrote, not on the system drive. So, Check all computer drives.

Comment: Astute answer but these so-called files, even if they exist, may not be residing with the same name on disk. And let's not forget how slim the chance is, given that the OP is seeing a blank page only.

Answer (score -2):

If localhost gives a blank page and no error, that doesn't mean that a webserver is running. It probably only means that the hosts file links localhost to 127.0.0.1 and nothing more. If a webserver was running, it would generate a result (webserver is working or something) or an error.

And yes you can put a blank html index file in the root folder, and that would result in a blank page as well. But no webserver does that by default, so you should have done that yourself.

So the default root folder, that depends on the server you're running, and as you're probably not running any webserver, there is no web root folder.

Comment: According to @mnmnc comment, if port 80 is listened, there must be some webserver. Don`t you agree?

Comment: @JoshCampbell No no no no! IIS and Apache are not the only webservers "out there". If you do not have any of them that does not mean you do not have a web server. If something is listening on the port 80 - you have something configured , some service that will respond to address `http://localhost`. And you will not get a blank page if nothing is listening. IE will say that cannot display the webpage, Chrome says webpage is not available.

Comment: @JustinasDūdėnas You need to install wireshark and start listening on the interface to see what is responding to the request sent while you try to access `http://localhost`. Search for a lines that begin with `HTTP/1.1 200 OK` or something similar - those lines will indicate response from webserver of anykind. If response from port 80 will have something different in the first lines - this will mean something other than webserver is configured on this port and it is most likely misconfiguration as port 80 for the sake of clarity should be reserved for http protocol communication.

Comment: @JustinasDūdėnas or even better - install Process Explorer from Microsoft Technet - you will see the list of the processes runnning. Choose a process, open it's properties and there is a tab named TCP/IP - you will see the connections opened. If for any process you will see the port 80 on the left column (Local Address) then this is a process that is listening on port 80.

Comment: ahh, that`s leading to some geekish investigation. I'll be too lazy, and try installing some webserver on top...

Comment: @JoshCampbell We are not discussing the possibility of serving the webpage without one of popular webservers. The discussion is about seeing blank page in a browser even if IIS or Apache is not installed. For example if other service is installed and configured to listen on port 80 - it will send some response to browser after connecting. This will not be a html but some unicode chars for example. Browser will accept and interpret this as empty response and will display the blank page. Connection on the network layer has been established hence no error message displayed by browser.

Comment: I agree, but at the same time, you are helping to solve my issue. As I decided to work-around it instead going deeper, we're staying somewhere in the middle. I'd gladly accept some answer anyway - a summary, or probably, the one rxt gave - whatever you think could serve a community.

Comment: @JustinasDūdėnas Try to follow those instructions: On the Start menu, click Run.
In the Open dialog box, type inetmgr, and then click OK. This will start the IIS control panel. I think you might have it installed after all since you stated that inetpub location exist under C:\ . So either it is installed or it was installed in the past. Let us know if you will see the control panel for IIS.

Comment: @mnmnc nope command not recognized. It remained from some former installation. I also checked running services.

Comment: @JustinasDūdėnas Ok. Download putty from here: http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/download.html
Open it and use connection type `telnet` to access the Host Name "localhost" on port 80. Click open and after black window appear with blinking cursor - hit Enter key couple of times. Copy what you see or make a print screen and show us.

Comment: @mnmnc not very informative :)
https://dl.dropbox.com/u/834290/test/putty%20%281%29.jpg
https://dl.dropbox.com/u/834290/test/putty%20%282%29.jpg

Comment: @JustinasDūdėnas Yes it is :) Two conclusions - there is a process listening on port 80 and it is not a web server. Now if you want to identify it you can either selectively stop services from `services.msc` and check if browser will display error message or you can install Process Explorer which i've mentioned earlier and review the properties of the processes to check if any one of them has a connection opened from port 80. Do this at the same time as trying to access the localhost webpage. I think only recently active connections will be visible.

Comment: @JustinasDūdėnas and include your print-screens in the Question above :)