# Better to block a host to 0.0.0.0 than to 127.0.0.1?

Tags: networking, dns, hosts-file

I have a few hosts that I would like to block in my `/etc/hosts` file. For that I need to define a bogus IP address that the DNS queries get resolved to.

Most of the tutorials I saw so far all mention `127.0.0.1` as the solution to that. But I was wondering if there is maybe a better or other address, that might already discard the connection earlier.

So I was thinking of using `0.0.0.0` in my `hosts`-file. Do you think this would work the same like using `127.0.0.1` to block certain hosts?

Comment: Unless you have a web server running on localhost, you'll probably end up with the same result. (The web server might respond if it's there though). I guess 0.0.0.0 would be slightly faster because your computer doesn't need to deal with the request.

Answer (score 16):

On Windows there **is** a difference: packets sent to `127.0.0.1` will end up bombarding whatever server you have running on your computer (and you [may be running a server without knowing it](https://superuser.com/q/43307/101850)), whereas trying to send packets `0.0.0.0` will immediately return with error code `1214` ([ERROR_INVALID_NETNAME](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/debug/system-error-codes--1000-1299-)).

TL;DR: Use `0.0.0.0`

Comment: That's what I meant. But I think this behavior is the same on all modern operating systems. I was just not sure if there is a problem with returning `0.0.0.0`, because maybe some software might not be able to handle this unexpected address?

Answer (score 1):

They're (usually) the same, and the packets end up the same: bombarding your own host with the requests and some time and traffic (on local interface) wasting some tiny amount of resources. (Same goes for any address in 127.0.0.0/8, say, 127.2.3.4.)

By the way it only works well if your host doesn't run the service you want to block (like using it for blocking webservers while your host does have a webserver), otherwise you will get replies from your own server. Using a definitely non-existing address (say, 192.168.255.254) would prevent this but would cause delays due to unreachable host for the connections.

Blocking by firewall usually works better. :-)